# disable caching on redshift by default

Tags: caching, amazon-redshift, query-cache

Since the 21 November Amazon Redshift introduced the default caching of result sets. Is there a way to disable caching by default on a Redshift database? There don't seem to be many docs on it at the moment.

Comment: i dont even see it implemented yet! but there is a cluster parameter that should disable it (when it is released properly) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_result_cache_for_session.html

Comment: @JonScott Yeah, currently we have to disable it each session, however it will, in future, mess with some of our API's as we are running very similar queries and we don't want result caching. We will have to go and change all of our connection initialization code to include the no caching option for the session. Hope they introduce to the cluster parameter groups soon.

Comment: are you sure you have this feature? Do you see the parameter when you run "show all;" and do you have the extra column on svl_qlog (you should see source_query column). ALSO I would be very keen to understand why you do not want this feature, what it is you are concerned about?

Comment: @JonScott We were running queries yesterday and kept getting skewed results. Ran `SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF` and fixed the problem. I like this feature in some cases, however some of our data changes very fast and is actively queried often. We witnessed a weird anomaly yesterday where even if we changed the where clause it still returned the cached result however when we changed the select statement by adding a constant return it returned the correct result. We will definitely be using this feature for some of our front ends but some of the back ends need to have it disabled.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I am intrigued that you have this feature - maybe its half implemented? please can you tell me - do you see the parameter when you run "show all;" and do you have the extra column on svl_qlog (you should see source_query column).?

Comment: ALSO - i am told that version must be > 1.0.1499, can you tell me what select version() ; returns?

Comment: @JonScott verion: `[redacted], Redshift 1.0.1564` Do indeed have the source_query column however `SHOW ALL;` reveals no option for caching only 
`name
analyze_threshold_percent
datestyle
extra_float_digits
query_group
search_path
statement_timeout
wlm_query_slot_count`.
I think half implemented is the right answer here, waiting with bated breath for the parameter group update. Do you know of anyway to rollback the version? (sorry comment formatting is limited, that `SHOW ALL;` List is all available options excluding name which is the header)

Comment: i wonder why you get a later version than me - my clusters are single node us-east-1. i have rebooted today and still get  1.0.1499

Comment: @JonScott We are running on eu-west-1a. I wish we were still running on that version haha. Would be a load off my chest. Can't see a way to roll back in the docs. Do you have `allow version upgrade on`?

Comment: us-east-1 is not yet patched! (just checked with aws support). You guys are the alpha testers :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help @JonScott

Answer (score 0):

You can switch it off in the server configuration.

The parameter name is `enable_result_cache_for_session` as mentioned in [the Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_result_cache_for_session.html).